# Symfony apply data transformer to getters/Entity field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Let's say we have an for orders entity like:

```
/**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_order")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

I created a DataTransformer with successfully adds or subtracts a starting number (e.g. 1000) to the order ID in forms.

However I would like to apply the same transformer to the getter, so when I request `$order->getId();` for e.g. id=1 it should return 1001;

Is this possible?

Comment: You should apply the transformer to the Form, not to the Entity

Comment: But what if I want to display the value e.g. in a twig template file without a form? I would have to add 1000 each time I display the order id.

Comment: If you want to do it in the entity, why not simply do `return $this->id + 1000;` in the getter, and `$this->id = $id - 1000;` in the setter? This way, internally, the values are always correct, but your interaction with the DB is always +1000

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. The ID should be the id, leave it alone. Just have a custom `getDisplayId()` that gives you the id in the format you want for display anywhere you need it. And use the real id to save/retrieve the object.